# Библиотеки на Telegram

Tags: c#, .net, telegram, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли библиотека для работы с Telegram с помощью .NET Framework?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, Вам подойдёт библиотека [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot).

Скорее всего, и освоение - с помощью примеров, котрые есть в репозитории на гитхабе - пройдет очень легко и непринуждённо.

Также, можно поискать другие варианты, потому что поиск по сочетанию "[Telegram .NET Framework](https://www.google.com/search?q=Telegram%20.NET%20Framework&oq=Telegram%20.NET%20Framework)" даёт еще множество вариантов.

Вы пишете в комментариях, что версия библиотеки для NET Framework не подходит.

Думаю, нам хорошо бы сравнить, что мы делаем, потому что у меня до сих пор всё работает.

Я попробовал - вроде всё ОК, вот "пруф": я создал WinForms проект на основе .NET Framework, добавил зависимость через NuGet package manager console, и смог получить вожделенную библиотеку:

[image: Проект]

[image: NuGet]

[image: Код]

Успехов!

Comment: Telegram.Bot требует .NET Core и .NET Standart, а у меня .NET Core не работает.

Comment: странно, но я сейчас открою какой нить из своих старых проектов - где  сам писал таких ботов... Открыл. там пэкэдж ставился командой Install-Package Telegram.Bot. Так что попробуйте еще раз - должно работать и для обычного (не Core) .Net Framework

Comment: а нужно через настройки проекта, или как-то по другому в visual studio?

Comment: Install-Package : Совпадения для указанных условий поиска и имени пакета "Telegram.Bot" не найдены. Чтобы просмотреть все доступные зарегистрированные источники пакетов, используйте кома
ндлет Get-PackageSource.
строка:1 знак:1
+ Install-Package Telegram.Bot
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Comment: понял, значит, с тех пор действительно поменялись требования... сейчас еще поищем! А нет варианта - использовать старую версию библиотеки?

Comment: Я попробовал у себя, и вроде всё ОК. Добавил картинки - проверьте, может, Вам это поможет?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, просто надо было использовать другую консоль и установить версию .NET 4.5.7!

Comment: ну, рад, что помогло!

Answer (score 0):

А еще есть TDLib, которая больше функциональна, со стороны клиента... https://github.com/tdlib/td

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [WTelegramClient](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient) для подключения к Telegram Client API (MTProto)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]